# Merging tensor rowwise with a vector in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I was hoping to implement a variation of PointNet (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.00593.pdf) in keras, but I'm having trouble repeating the context vector (g) a variable amount of times so that I can Concatenate it rowwise with a previous layer that lacks context(pre). I tried Repeat() and keras.backend.Tile().

```
input = Input(shape=(None,3))
x = TimeDistributed(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))(input)
pre = TimeDistributed(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))(x)
g = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(pre)
x = Lambda(merge_on_single, output_shape=(None,512))([pre,g])
print(x.shape)
```

This is the lambda definition I came up with.

```
def merge_on_single(v):
#v[0] is variable length tensor, v[1] is the single vector

return Concatenate()([K.repeat(v[1],K.get_variable_shape(v[0])),v[0]])
```

However the following error occurs:

TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'Pack' Op have types [int32, , int32] that don't all match.

UPDATE:

So I was able to get the layers to not give errors by doing the following:

```
input = Input(shape=(None,3))

num_point = K.placeholder(input.get_shape()[1].value, dtype=tf.int32)

#first global feature layer
x = TimeDistributed(Dense(512, activation = 'relu'))(input)
x = TimeDistributed(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))(x)
g = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
g = K.reshape(g,(-1,1,256))
g = K.tile(x, [1,num_point,1])
concat_feat = K.concatenate([x, g])
```

but now, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the culprit is `K.get_variable_shape(v[0])`. Since `v[0]` is of type `int32` (as specified by your error), when you get the shape it returns None. Concatenate wants all inputs to be of the same type.